# Norm controls the components of a matrix- proof?

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

For certain norms (such as the Frobenius norm) it is clear that the norm provides component-wise control - each component is at most as large as the norm in magnitude.

How do we establish this for some abstract matrix norm?

Comment: If $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm, then so is $\alpha \|\cdot\|$ for any $\alpha >0$. So, you can't in general bound the components by the norm.

Comment: Indeed, but what if we add the condition that the norm of the delta matrices (all zeros, and 1 at some position) should be unity? This would probably take care of the normalization issue (suggested above)? Btw, my original question was motivated by the search for a norm which could take values less than unity, and yet whose components could be larger than unity in magnitude!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can define the norm $n(A) = \max_{i,j} |[A]_{ij}|$. Since all norms (on,
say, $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$) are equivalent, so there are strictly positive constants $a,b$ so that $a \|A\| \le n(A) \le b \|A\|$, and
so all components are bounded by $b \|A\|$.

Comment: Indeed, but what if we add the condition that the norm of the delta matrices (all zeros, and 1 at some position) should be unity? This would probably take care of the normalization issue (suggested above)? Btw, my original question was motivated by the search for a norm which could take values less than unity, and yet whose components could be larger than unity in magnitude!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a given matrix norm, and define $c_1=\min_{i,j} \|e_ie_j^T\|$ and $c_2=\max_{i}\|e_ie_i^T\|$, where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is the standard basis. Then for any matrix $A$, its $(i,j)$ component $A_{ij}$ can be written $A_{ij}=e_i^TAe_j$, and we have
\begin{align*}
|A_{ij}| &\leq |A_{ij}|c_1^{-1}\|e_ie_j^T\|\\
&=c_1^{-1}\| A_{ij} e_ie_j^T\| \\
&= c_1^{-1}\|e_iA_{ij}e_j^T\| \\
&= c_1^{-1}\|e_ie_i^TAe_je_j^T\| \\
&\leq c_1^{-1}\|e_ie_i^T\|\|A\|\|e_je_j^T\|\\
&\leq c_1^{-1}c_2^2\|A\|
\end{align*}
Thus the components of $A$ may be bounded by a constant factor of $\|A\|$.